# Can't install numpy on pypy 3 - OSX

Tags: python, numpy, pypy

I've been trying to install numpy on the latest pypy3. I tried both the precompiled binaries on pypy.org and the latest brew version, and both yield the same output. I also tried pypy2, installing xcode command line tools, installing the full xcode - nothing.

The output I get is the following. I can't seem to wrap my head over this one.

```
Alexandres-MBP ~ pip_pypy3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/26/07472b0de91851b6656cbc86e2f0d5d3a3128e7580f23295ef58b6862d6c/numpy-1.16.1.zip
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/bin/pypy3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-record-csvehs47/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Running from numpy source directory.

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpj6ky3mz7/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpj6ky3mz7/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpj6ky3mz7/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpj6ky3mz7/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpj6ky3mz7/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpj6ky3mz7/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpj6ky3mz7
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpj6ky3mz7/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpj6ky3mz7/file.c
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp_qfz2skb/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp_qfz2skb/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp_qfz2skb/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp_qfz2skb/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp_qfz2skb/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp_qfz2skb/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp_qfz2skb
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp_qfz2skb/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp_qfz2skb/file.c
      libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmprx9e1fn5/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmprx9e1fn5/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmprx9e1fn5/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmprx9e1fn5/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmprx9e1fn5/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmprx9e1fn5/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmprx9e1fn5
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmprx9e1fn5/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmprx9e1fn5/file.c
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpiv6n26aa/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpiv6n26aa/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpiv6n26aa/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpiv6n26aa/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpiv6n26aa/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpiv6n26aa/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpiv6n26aa
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpiv6n26aa/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpiv6n26aa/file.c
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp13puxf7n/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp13puxf7n/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp13puxf7n/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp13puxf7n/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp13puxf7n/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp13puxf7n/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp13puxf7n
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp13puxf7n/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp13puxf7n/file.c
      libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkr81mv8t/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkr81mv8t/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkr81mv8t/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkr81mv8t/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkr81mv8t/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkr81mv8t/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkr81mv8t
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkr81mv8t/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkr81mv8t/file.c
      libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpjyy9xzn_/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpjyy9xzn_/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpjyy9xzn_/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpjyy9xzn_/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpjyy9xzn_/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpjyy9xzn_/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpjyy9xzn_
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpjyy9xzn_/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpjyy9xzn_/file.c
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpad2wybxr/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpad2wybxr/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpad2wybxr/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpad2wybxr/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpad2wybxr/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpad2wybxr/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpad2wybxr
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpad2wybxr/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpad2wybxr/file.c
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      FOUND:
        extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
        extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

      FOUND:
        extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
        extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpvivpla8q/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpvivpla8q/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpvivpla8q/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpvivpla8q/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpvivpla8q/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpvivpla8q/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpvivpla8q
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpvivpla8q/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpvivpla8q/file.c
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpukmeglqd/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpukmeglqd/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpukmeglqd/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpukmeglqd/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpukmeglqd/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpukmeglqd/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpukmeglqd
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpukmeglqd/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpukmeglqd/file.c
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpeudl3irx/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpeudl3irx/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpeudl3irx/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpeudl3irx/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpeudl3irx/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpeudl3irx/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpeudl3irx
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpeudl3irx/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpeudl3irx/file.c
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp7jh7fy0v/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp7jh7fy0v/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp7jh7fy0v/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp7jh7fy0v/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp7jh7fy0v/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp7jh7fy0v/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp7jh7fy0v
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp7jh7fy0v/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp7jh7fy0v/file.c
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp83v2a7ej/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp83v2a7ej/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp83v2a7ej/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp83v2a7ej/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp83v2a7ej/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp83v2a7ej/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp83v2a7ej
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp83v2a7ej/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp83v2a7ej/file.c
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

[...]

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpcwipzrv9/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpcwipzrv9/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpcwipzrv9/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpcwipzrv9/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpcwipzrv9/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpcwipzrv9/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpcwipzrv9
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpcwipzrv9/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpcwipzrv9/file.c
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpg0zj9qr_/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpg0zj9qr_/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpg0zj9qr_/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpg0zj9qr_/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpg0zj9qr_/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpg0zj9qr_/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpg0zj9qr_
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpg0zj9qr_/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpg0zj9qr_/file.c
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp16sr7wk2/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp16sr7wk2/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp16sr7wk2/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp16sr7wk2/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp16sr7wk2/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp16sr7wk2/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp16sr7wk2
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp16sr7wk2/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp16sr7wk2/file.c
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp3q4ns9eu/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp3q4ns9eu/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp3q4ns9eu/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp3q4ns9eu/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp3q4ns9eu/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp3q4ns9eu/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp3q4ns9eu
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp3q4ns9eu/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp3q4ns9eu/file.c
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpmtsagm8c/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpmtsagm8c/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpmtsagm8c/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpmtsagm8c/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpmtsagm8c/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpmtsagm8c/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpmtsagm8c
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpmtsagm8c/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpmtsagm8c/file.c
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkw31na5h/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkw31na5h/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkw31na5h/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkw31na5h/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkw31na5h/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkw31na5h/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkw31na5h
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkw31na5h/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpkw31na5h/file.c
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp4oghquyx/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp4oghquyx/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp4oghquyx/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp4oghquyx/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp4oghquyx/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp4oghquyx/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp4oghquyx
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp4oghquyx/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmp4oghquyx/file.c
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpf3oghm2l/var
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpf3oghm2l/var/folders
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpf3oghm2l/var/folders/rn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpf3oghm2l/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpf3oghm2l/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T
    creating /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpf3oghm2l/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpf3oghm2l
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpf3oghm2l/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/tmpf3oghm2l/file.c
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

      FOUND:
        extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
        extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

    /usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib-python/3/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build/src.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/src.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.5/numpy
    creating build/src.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.5/numpy/distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu95', 'nag', 'absoft', 'ibm', 'intel', 'gnu', 'g95', 'pg']'
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Found executable /usr/local/bin/gfortran
    /private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/gnu.py:353: UserWarning: Env. variable MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET set to 10.3
      flags = GnuFCompiler.get_flags_linker_so(self)
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    customize Gnu95FCompiler using config
    C compiler: cc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/include -c'
    cc: _configtest.c
    cc -pthread -arch x86_64 _configtest.o -o _configtest
    ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.4
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/setup.py", line 415, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/setup.py", line 407, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib-python/3/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib-python/3/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib-python/3/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 62, in run
        r = self.setuptools_run()
      File "/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
        return distutils_install.run(self)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib-python/3/distutils/command/install.py", line 549, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib-python/3/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib-python/3/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 47, in run
        old_build.run(self)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib-python/3/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib-python/3/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/libexec/lib-python/3/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
        self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
      File "/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 292, in build_library_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
      File "/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 375, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 667, in get_mathlib_info
        raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/6.0.0/bin/pypy3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-record-csvehs47/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/rn/d8wvxv0n7kg2jq31bfhfpxw00000gn/T/pip-install-gsqxbr53/numpy/
```

Comment: No one has a clue? Is there info missing in my question or something?